# Is it possible to change Magento backend language for one user only?

Tags: magento, localization, internationalization

We got multi-lingual team, and couple of members do not speak each others languages. Is it possible to set Magento backend in separate languages for corresponding users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

each user can choose a language with the localization drop down at the left bottom of every admin pages

Comment: Cool. But does it save the choice anywhere? Seems one needs to choose the language on every login.

Comment: I don't think magento save it anywhere: after logout and login the default language is back. If this is really important, it shouldn't be very complicated to write a module for that. If you're interested I could give you some hints.

Comment: At least the Community Edition seems to only come with english and all language packs I found only translate the frontend.

Answer (score 5):

You should find that this module from AOE allows you to save the user's preferred language for the admin interface: https://github.com/AOEmedia/Aoe_BackendDefaultLanguage

Once the user has logged in, navigate to System>My Account and the last field (select drop-down) is language).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it is in the pay version of magento, but it seems that the community edition has only the ability to change the backend language to one language regardless of who is logged in. Maybe you code this feature by yourself or you keep the english language.